# IoC resolving issue after upgrading to 5.8

Tags: laravel, ioc-container, laravel-5.8

Hoping someone can help me,

I am updating from version 5.7 to 5.8 and I am now having issues with our repository setup.

I am using the repository pattern, for each repository we have a contract. I have a service provider (this is setup to be deferred) to bind the contracts to the repositories so when type hinted the interfaces / contracts in the controllers the repository is injected in.

We also have a service provider (also setup to be deferred) that when the repository is resolved it gets some config data from a config file and calls methods on the repository to setup attributes.

This all worked great on 5.7 but after upgrading to 5.8 it doesn't. If I switch the controllers to type hint the repository instead of the contract it works, but obviously if / when we change the repository we would have to amend all places this is referenced, completely against purpose of coding to an interface and injecting this.

Hopefully I've explained that well enough!

Has anyone come up against this or similar? I've checked the upgrade notes and 5.8 no longer uses the defer property as it implements the interface which I am doing but I can't see anything else and I am struggling to debug it any further.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#deferred-service-providers

Any help any one can offer would be great.

If I switch back to 5.7 there is no issue, or if use the actual repository and typehint this in the controller there is no issue, it is happening only when using the contract / interface

Here is the service provider for the Repository to set the properties of it

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Repositories\Erp;

use App\Models\ERP_OLTP\WorkOrderStatus as WorkOrderStatusModel;
use App\Repositories\Erp\EloquentMaterialRequirements;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository as ConfigRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MaterialRequirementsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->resolving(
            EloquentMaterialRequirements::class,
            function (EloquentMaterialRequirements $repo, $app) {
                $config = $app[ConfigRepositoryInterface::class]->get('materialRequirements');

                $statusIds = array_reduce(
                    $config['workOrderStatuses'],
                    function ($acc, $statusCode) {
                        $acc[] = WorkOrderStatusModel::STATUS[$statusCode];

                        return $acc;
                    },
                    []
                );

                $repo->setDemandStatusIds($statusIds);
                $repo->setDemandWeekCount($config['weekCount']);
                $repo->setAverageUsageWeekCount($config['averageWeeklyUsageMaxAgeWeeks']);
            }
        );
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            EloquentMaterialRequirements::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is the service provider for repositories to be binded to contracts

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository as ConfigRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ErpRepositoriesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        foreach ($this->getBindings() as $contract => $implementation) {
            $this->app->bind($contract, $implementation);
        }
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        $services = [];

        foreach (array_keys($this->getBindings()) as $contract) {
            $services[] = $contract;
        }

        return $services;
    }

    private function getBindings(): array
    {
        return $this->app[ConfigRepositoryInterface::class]->get('repositories.bindings');
    }
}
```

here is the config.repositories, i've removed other repositories to minify it

```php
<?php

use App\Contracts\Erp\Repositories as Contracts;
use App\Managers\Erp\Repositories as Managers;
use App\Repositories\Erp as Repositories;

return [
    'bindings' => [
        Contracts\MaterialRequirements::class => Repositories\EloquentMaterialRequirements::class,
    ],
];
```

It simply never calls the MaterialRequirementsServiceProvider or if it does it isn't resolving the EloquentMaterialRequirements::class and therefore setting properties. I get no errors, no exceptions, nothing to go off

Comment: Did you try to bind the FQDN of the interface in a string instead of using the FQDN followed by `::class`? For instance, `App\Contracts\Erp\Repositories\MaterialRequirements` instead of `Contracts\MaterialRequirements::class`. The same idea would apply for the `$this->app->resolving` first parameter.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, that made no difference, i tried completely clear all cache, all optimisations and then didn't defer the service provider and it works, then deferring the provider and it works, seems every time i deploy i have to do this now which is a real pain